# Compare two joints position with Kinect

Tags: c#, kinect

I want to make a Kinect program thanks to, when your left hand X position cross your right shoulder X position, it plays the following slide on PowerPoint. I've already done the program part which draws the skeleton stream, and it's work correctly. For the second part, I've tried this :

```
private void NextSlide(Skeleton skeleton)
{
    Joint leftHand = skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft];
    Joint spine = skeleton.Joints[JointType.Spine];
    Joint shoulderRight = skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderRight];
    bool check = false;
    if (leftHand.Position.X == shoulderRight.Position.X && check == false)
    {
        check = true;
        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{RIGHT}");
    }
    if (leftHand.Position.X == spine.Position.X && check == true)
    {
        check = false
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain me what is the problem in my code ?
Thanks,

**Edit :**

I've also tried this :

```
private void NextSlide(Skeleton skeleton)
{
    Joint leftHand = skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft];
    Joint spine = skeleton.Joints[JointType.Spine];
    Joint shoulderRight = skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderRight];
    double lefthandposition = (int)leftHand.Position.X;
    double shoulderrightposition = (int)shoulderRight.Position.X;
    double spineposition = (int)spine.Position.X;
    bool turn = false;
    double right = lefthandposition - shoulderrightposition;
    bool finish = false;
    double ok = lefthandposition - spineposition;
    if (right < 0)
    {
        turn = true;
    }
    if (ok > 0)
    {
        finish = true;
    }
    bool check = false;
    if (turn == true && check == false && finish == false)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{RIGHT}");
        check = true;
        turn = false;
    }
    if (finish == true && check == true && turn == false)
    {
        check = false;
        finish = false;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work too :/

Comment: The odds of the two positions ever being exactly equal are pretty slim. You might get it to work by just waving your hand around near your shoulder for a while. Also, you used `JointType.ShoulderLeft` rather than `JointType.ShoulderRight`.

Comment: Sorry for the ShoulderLeft rather than ShoulderRight, in my code, I've written ShoulderRight, but when I copied out, I've done a mistake :/. Else, how must I do to get it work by just waving my hand around near my shoulder for a while.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble you are running into is that you using `==` as a check.  You will rarely, if ever, run into a situation where two joints are exactly the same value.  You need to be using `>=` or `<=` for your checks, depending on your needs.

For example, check the `JointType.LeftHand >= JointType.RightShoulder`, and that `JointType.LeftHand <= JointType.Spine`, for your position checks.

Another solution could be to use an existing gesture library to accomplish what you want.  Here are two of them:

- http://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/
- https://github.com/EvilClosetMonkey/Fizbin.Kinect.Gestures

The Fizbin library's GitHub page explains how to set up and execute on existing gestures: [Executing on Gestures](https://github.com/EvilClosetMonkey/Fizbin.Kinect.Gestures#executing-on-gestures).  Included in the existing gesture set is a "Swipe Right" and a "Swipe Left" gesture, which execute similar to what you are wanting to do.

The GitHub pages goes into more detail, but a quick rundown would start with setting up the gesture library and a callback:

```
gestureController = new GestureController();
gestureController.GestureRecognized += OnGestureRecognized;
```

You'd then initialize the gesture(s) you want to use:

```
IRelativeGestureSegment[] swipeleftSegments = new IRelativeGestureSegment[3];
swipeleftSegments[0] = new SwipeLeftSegment1();
swipeleftSegments[1] = new SwipeLeftSegment2();
swipeleftSegments[2] = new SwipeLeftSegment3();
gestureController.AddGesture("SwipeLeft", swipeleftSegments);
```

You can modify the existing gesture components or write your own.  The several examples will demonstrate how you can compare joint positions.  For example, the first segment in the "SwipeLeft" gesture follows:

```
public class SwipeLeftSegment1 : IRelativeGestureSegment
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks the gesture.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="skeleton">The skeleton.</param>
    /// <returns>GesturePartResult based on if the gesture part has been completed</returns>
    public GesturePartResult CheckGesture(Skeleton skeleton)
    {

        // right hand in front of right shoulder
        if (skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.Z < skeleton.Joints[JointType.ElbowRight].Position.Z && skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.Y < skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderCenter].Position.Y)
        {
            // right hand below shoulder height but above hip height
            if (skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.Y < skeleton.Joints[JointType.Head].Position.Y && skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.Y > skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipCenter].Position.Y)
            {
                // right hand right of right shoulder
                if (skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.X > skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderRight].Position.X)
                {
                    return GesturePartResult.Succeed;
                }
                return GesturePartResult.Pausing;
            }
            return GesturePartResult.Fail;
        }
        return GesturePartResult.Fail;
    }
}
```

Notice it goes through a series of joint checks and returns one of three results:

- Succeed: The gesture has completed in full (fired when all the 'if' statements succeed)
- Pausing: The gesture is partially complete (fired when you want to indicate the gesture is "in motion" but not complete)
- Fail: The gesture is not being executed at all

When you have the gesture you want initialized you just need to send the 'skeleton' data to the gesture library:

```
private void OnSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (SkeletonFrame frame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
    {
            if (frame == null)
                    return;

            // resize the skeletons array if needed
            if (skeletons.Length != frame.SkeletonArrayLength)
                    skeletons = new Skeleton[frame.SkeletonArrayLength];

            // get the skeleton data
            frame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);

            foreach (var skeleton in skeletons)
            {
                    // skip the skeleton if it is not being tracked
                    if (skeleton.TrackingState != SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
                            continue;

                    // update the gesture controller
                    gestureController.UpdateAllGestures(skeleton);
            }
    }
}
```

Finally, execute on the gesture:

```
private void OnGestureRecognized(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.GestureName)
    {
            case "SwipeLeft":
                    // do what you want to do
                    break;

            default:
                    break;
    }
}
```